# Deconstructing a [FromBody] object with 1 property in .net core API C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, destructuring

I just converted a project to .net core and one of the changes is that I can now only have 1 [FromBody] attribute passed to a controller action. Previously I was passing in a JSON object into the body like so:

```
{
    property1: 1,
    property2: 2
}
```

and could receive those 2 properties in the controller like so:

```
public doSomething([FromBody]int property1, [FromBody]int property2)
```

now I have to create a new class for the parameters that get passed in through the body:

```
public class DoSomethingParams {
    public int property1;
    public int property2;
}

public doSomething([FromBody]DoSomethingParams bodyParams)
```

This creates a whole lot more code, especially when I have to pass in 10 or more parameters for a call, and it feels very inefficient to me.

In Javascript there are destructuring operations that I could use one aforementioned object like this: 
`let property1 = {property1};`. Is there any similar alternative in C#? I read about [tuple deconstructing in C# v7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/#user-content-deconstruction) but I'm not quite sure that it helps me here (eg. adding `[FromBody](int property1, int property2)` as an argument doesn't work. (Identifier expected error))

Is there a more efficient way to deconstruct the JSON object I'm passing in besides creating a class skeleton for it? Thanks for the help!

Comment: "*This creates a whole lot more code*" - Really though? It's just a class and it gives you a strongly typed model. After all, C# is an object-oriented language. Sounds like a good benefit to me.

Comment: what framework are you converting from that allowed multiple `[FromBody]` params?

Comment: @mcheaah More code is not a negative. More code can make code easier to read and more maintainable.

Comment: You should use this: `public doSomething(int property1, int property2)`, remove `[FormBody]` will be as simple as before.

Comment: @DavidG what about in a situation where I just need to pass in 1 integer? 
`public doSomething([FromBody]int property1)` seems much cleaner than creating a  class for 1 property? and the strongly typed model benefit doesn't really apply here.

Comment: @Dongdong The model binding in .net core doesn't recognize the properties without adding the [FromBody] attribute.

Comment: Yes, if you have a single parameter, then you don't need a class, but for more than one, I would encapsulate it into an object that you can easily pass around. Remember none of your logic should exist inside the action method anyway.

Comment: @DavidG thanks. Any recommendation on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom model provider to achieve that. check this package it does just that: https://github.com/m6t/M6T.Core.TupleModelBinder

You just need to add the custom binder to your binder providers at the first position:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
  {
      options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new TupleModelBinderProvider());
  })
```

and then you will be able to use the Tuple deconstruct:

```
public doSomething((int property1, int property2, string other) bodyParams) {
  // bodyParams.property1
  // bodyParams.property2
  // bodyParams.other
}
```